# Column number in mysql 'WHERE' condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

How is it possible to select the first column in the `Where clause`. I am trying to make a `php` function to retrieve table data based on the `id`, yet since the titles of the `id` columns are different in various tables, I need to refer to the first column in the Where clause as the first column is always the id column.

The scenario would be something like the following, but it throws errors and says that there is an error in the SQL syntax.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE column(1) = :id");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL doesn't have any such function. It doesn't seem very robust to depend on the order of columns like this.

Comment: The only times you can refer to columns by number is in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Not a very good idea.  But that query could be dynamically generated via `information_schema.columns.ordinal_position`, if you really want to do this.

Comment: Thanks dear @Barmar. Any strategies to bypass the problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52559333/2943403 (unanswered duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no built-in way to do this, I came up with the following code block to get the first column and then use it in my SELECT statements.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->query("SHOW columns FROM $table");
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)[0];
```

I think this strategy is a bit shorter than `Barmar`'s, though his is completely right and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. But you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column names.

```
$col_stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
    SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() 
        AND ordinal_position = 1 
        AND table_name = :table");
$col_stmt->execute([':table' => $table]);
$first_col = $col_stmt->fetchColumn();
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$first_col` = :id");
```

Comment: How about in a single trip to the database?

Comment: You could do the same thing in a stored procedure. Can't think of any other way to do it with a single trip to the DB.